# NPE when using ThreadLocal + AtomicLong in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicinteger

I'm initializing using `public static ThreadLocal<AtomicLong> count = new ThreadLocal<>();`

How do I use AtomicLong method for `count`? The below throws a NPE:

```
count.get().addAndGet(records.size());
```

Comment: Your `ThreadLocal` has no initial value.

Comment: Create one with the `ThreadLocal.withInitial(Supplier)` factory method.

Comment: records is not null. And I tried `count.get().set(0L)` but this threw a NPE as well

Comment: There's no point in using `AtomicLong` in a thread-local context. Just use `Long`.